# Get the current row number in DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to get the current datatable row count number that is being edited. Basically, I want to add a row, only if it is the last row in the datatable. Is it possible to get the current absolute index in datatable?

For checking the total number of rows I am using `table.rows().count()`

Comment: You didn't share your code so it is pretty hard to guess what exactly you mean by *current row* and how exactly you mark the rows being edited. So far, the best answer you could get is "yes, that's possible".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining both the below answers fixed my issue

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> asfua</td>
        <td> asfua</td>
        <td> asfua</td>
        <td onclick="Edit(this)"> asfua</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> dkbsdf</td>
        <td> dkbsdf</td>
        <td> dkbsdf</td>
        <td onclick="Edit(this)"> dkbsdf</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script>
    function Edit(obj) {
        console.log(table.row(obj).index());
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use row().index();
Here is the link:
https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().index()

Answer (score 1):

This is easy when you pass `this` in you EditFunc(this) and from simple jquery you can get the row index number eg.

```
 <table>
        <tr>
            <td> asfua</td>
            <td> asfua</td>
            <td> asfua</td>
            <td onclick="Edit(this)"> asfua</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> dkbsdf</td>
            <td> dkbsdf</td>
            <td> dkbsdf</td>
            <td onclick="Edit(this)"> dkbsdf</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script>
        function Edit(obj) {
            console.log($(obj).parent().index())
        }
    </script>
```

Data table row index will be consoled of the relative td